# How to find sum of counter field using cqlengine?

Tags: orm, cassandra, counter, cqlengine

I have a post table with fields **post_id** and **total**(**counter** field), which stores the viewers count for the post for a day. How can I get total viewers count for a post using **cqlengine** orm?
a Flask application with cassandra as backend

I'm up to this now:

```
Posts.objects.filter(post_id=11)
```

which filters all rows for the post with id=11, how to find the sum of **total**(column name) from these rows?

Answer (score 0):

You have to send another query to counter table for getting counter value of this id then marge two result.you can try this way..